# Открытие страниц через Chrome API

Tags: java, android, activity, google-chrome

День добрый! Как VK и прочие приложения открывают страницу через Chrome в таком виде? Какие это дает преимущества и как это сделать? 
[image: пример]

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: @temq Спасибо! Не знал, как это называется.